# How to change Item in Gridview on ButtonClick from another Activity?

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, baseadapter

I created an app based on [Android GridView Layout Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial)

which works fine.

Now I got 2 Activities (Main + FullImage) + the ImageAdapter.

When I am in the FullImageActivity and click a Button that I created, I want to change the Item of the GridView in the MainActivity that brought me to the FullImageActivity.

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

or whatever

Comment: http://www.androider.me/2013/08/android-select-gridview-item-highlight.html

Comment: So you want to highlight Grid?

Comment: I want to change the Item (from the GridView) in the MainActivity that brought me to the FullImageActivity. And I want to Change it while I'm "sitting" in the FullImageActivity.

Comment: you can get the griditem by using getChildat()

Answer (score 0):

I think this may Help you to Highlight Grid Button . . .

Use selector to highlight item.

In drawable folder create a xml file

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

and **set listSelector** of your gridview like

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Reply for any Queries....